# Plotting a histogram with C++ RGB Values

Tags: c++, image, graph, pixel, histogram

I've gotten the RGB values of each and every single pixel in the picture, now what i will like to do is to plot a histogram based on the RGB. So there will be 3 line(Blue,Green,Red) going up and down depending on the pixel value. But despite that, i do not how to find a way to go about it. Is there any guidance i can make use of? Thank you!

P.S : I am using C++ Project Application, not C++ Console Application.

Edit: I am using Microsoft Visual Studio 2010

Edit: I tried plotting a X and Y axis.

I know the Y can stay constant, but on the X axis, the X axis must show the RGB values while going up the Y axis. Is there any way to go around it?

Sorry if i sound confused, hopefully you get what i mean.

Comment: Libaries meaning as in OpenCV, Magick, etc. Sorry if you misunderstood my intention, is there any way to draw the histogram with lines in the application?

Comment: Without going into details... just draw on a piece of paper how you plan to plot a 3D histogram + counts (4D total), and realize that as asked your question does not make much sense.

Comment: I am currently using Microsoft Visual Studio 2010

Comment: Should really change your question, your losing your reputation.

Comment: Okay, thank you. I've changed the question, but yet i am still stucked.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The functions `MoveTo` and `LineTo` are used to draw lines in Windows, usually in response to the WM_PAINT message. Select a pen of the appropriate color into the DC before calling them.

You'll need to scale the histogram values to the Y scale. Choose a maximum Y value, and for each histogram value use `y = histogram[x] * height / maxY`.

Comment: Hi Mark, MoveToEx(hdc, 0, 0, NULL); What do you mean by y = histogram[x] * height / maxY?

I do understand that histogram[x] = pixel value * 200 / Max height.

So how do i declare the histogram method?

Comment: @Cnoob, my usage of `histogram[x]` was meant to mean the count of pixels at a value of `x` for one of `Blue,Green,Red`.

Answer (score 0):

As I can understand from your question you are a beginner in such tasks. In such a case I recommend you to us some 3rd party GUI library which does most of work for you. The best choice is probably [Qt by Nokia](http://qt.nokia.com/products/) (Visual Studio add-in is available) and the free library called [QWT](http://qwt.sourceforge.net/) based on Qt which is perfectly suitable for plotting histograms, spectrograms and a lot of other technical plotting. At least you can go through the source code and inspire yourself how to do it your own way.

Of course you can do it by using native Windows API ([GDI+](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms533798%28v=VS.85%29.aspx)), but it is really a pain.

Comment: Thank you, but sorry vitakot.

As i cannot use any 3rd party GUI library (even though i really want to), but I am unable to use it due to limitations on my side. What i can only really do now is to plot histogram using X and Y axis with Drawline..